# Hide a button jQuery based on user role - MVC C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery to create buttons dynamically, this is the code to create the buttons `HTML`

```
    var createButtons = function (buttonsObject) {
        var buttons = buttonsObject;
        var htmlButtons = [];

        $.each(buttons, function (name, props) {
            var css = "";
            if (!props.enabled) {
                css = " hidden";
            }
            var tempBtn = $("<button/>", {
                text: props.Text,
                id: "btn_" + props.Text,
                "class": props.css + " pull-left" + css,
                click: props.click
            }).attr({ "style": "margin-right: 5px;" });

            htmlButtons.push(tempBtn);

        });
        return htmlButtons;
    };
```

And then I can pass in buttons like this:

```
        buttons: {
            dlt: {
                Text: "Delete",
                css: "btn btn-danger",
                enabled: true,
                click: function () {
                    // Do something
                }
            },
            update: {
                Text: "Update",
                css: "btn btn-primary",
                enabled: true,
                click: function () {
                  // Do something
                }
            },
            create: {
                Text: "Create",
                css: "btn btn-success",
                enabled: true,
                click: function () {
                  //Do something
                }
            }

        }
```

Now I have added a property 'enabled', which will decide if the button should be displayed or not.

Everything is working as expected.

Now the button has to be hidden if the user does not have permission to perform the action.

The user Roles are saved in the User Session, and can be accessed in the View using Razor C# using:

```
@{
  var createSIMPackage = SessionHandler.UserSession.UserFeatures.Contains("Create SIM Package");
}
```

The button should be hidden when `createSIMPackage`  is FALSE and should be displayed when `createSIMPackage` is TRUE.

I thought of putting the value of `createSIMPackage` in a Hidden field, but it won't be good practice as the application size increases.

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="@createSIMPackage" id="createSIMPackage" />
```

and then JS:

```
create: {
Text: "Create",
css: "btn btn-success",
enabled: $('#creatSimPackage').val(),
click: function () {
   //Do something
}
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: You can just assign it direct to a javascript variable - `var createSIMPackage = '@SessionHandler.UserSession.UserFeatures.Contains("Create SIM Package")'` (but may be better to assign to a view model or `ViewBag` property in the controller and use (say) `var createSIMPackage = '@ViewBag.CreateSIMPackage'`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that works fine if the jquery is in the view.cshtml file (which I am doing in some places) - but won't work if I am creating the buttons in a JS file.

Comment: In that case you could pass the value to the file, say in a `Initalize()` function, or an additional parameter to your existing function